# How to specifically ignore the hibernate quoted identifier attribute on a column in spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have tables in postgres that all of them and their columns named with the doublequotes `""`. To make it easier, then I set the `globally_quoted_identifier` to `true`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

However, I have a table that doesn't have a primary key that can have multiple rows with absolutely same data (In this case, this is necessary), thus I need to set the `@Id` column to the `CTID` column of the table (CTID is default row id in postgres). This resulted error as the `CTID` is supposedly not enclosed by the quotes.

I know that I can set the property above to `false` and put doublequotes with escapes on the POJOs. However, I currently have 6 POJOs and each having around 5 columns.

Then, is it more feasible/easier way to ignore the doublequote on the CTID column so it can run properly?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has only 3 [quoting options](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_quoting_options):

- `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers`
- `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions`
- `hibernate.auto_quote_keyword`

You can skip quoting only for [column definitions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition()) out of the box that's all. 
Also it is hard and tedious to define quoting for each column manually.

**Solution:**

But fortunately, you can define a custom naming strategy.

You can just extend standard [CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy.html).

There you can skip quoting for specific column names, just create [Identifier](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/Identifier.html) without quoting [getIdentifier(name.getText(), false, jdbcEnvironment)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy.html#getIdentifier-java.lang.String-boolean-org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment-) for `CTID` column.

```java
package com.project.naming;

import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

public class CustomNamingStrategy extends CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy {
    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        if ("CTID".equalsIgnoreCase(name.getText())) {
            name = getIdentifier(name.getText(), false, jdbcEnvironment);
        }
        return super.toPhysicalColumnName(name, jdbcEnvironment);
    }
}
```

Define your custom naming strategy in server properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=com.project.naming.CustomNamingStrategy
```

Example of DDL generation:

```sql
    create table "example" (
         ctid bigint generated by default as identity,
        "name" varchar(15),
        "owner_id" bigint not null)
```

Example of generated query:

```sql
select 
       example0_.ctid as ctid1_1_, 
       example0_."name" as name2_1_, 
       example0_."owner_id" as owner_id3_1_ 
from 
       "example" example0_ 
where 
       example0_.ctid1_1_ = ?
```